# Symfony2 routing-structure "/" and "/news/page/{page}"

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-routing

is there a way to combine my two routes "/" and "/news/page/{page}" so that I dont't need two routes with same defaults only to show a start-page? I'm using knpmenubundle and get trouble with marking menu item as active if one element has two routes.

Comment: you could use a redirect on the / to /news/page/{page}

Comment: Is this a "good" solution from usability and SEO?

Comment: why dont you define two routes for the same action?
eg. `@Route("/", defaults={"page": "homepage"}) @Route("/news/page/{page}`

Comment: I did this but while using knpmenubundle i have to set the route for the menu-entry to the one which includes the pagination so if you go on the site no menu-entry is active